# getResultList() generate org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql

I'm aware that this problem has been asked several times before. But I believe I have a very different case, I'm currently encountering this error when invoking the getResultList() method, not when persisting.

Note that I'm using:
-javaee6
-seam3-security
-jboss7.1.3
-postgresql

Series of events:
1.) After login, I saved my user in picketlink using the interface org.picketlink.idm.api.User:

```
setUser(new MyUser(user));
```

I should be able to retrieve the user using ((MyUser)identity.getuser()).getUser();

2.) Now I have a BusinessAccount entity that has OneToMany relationship with AccounType:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ACCOUNT")
public class BusinessAccount extends BaseEntity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID")
    private AccountType accountType;
}

@Entity()
@Table(name = "T_ACCOUNT_TYPE")
public class AccountType extends BaseEntity {   
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_TYPE", length = 20) 
    private AccountTypeEnum accountTypeEnum;    
}
```

My problem is I have a service: BusinessAccountService that extends BaseService, which calls getAccounts and it throws this error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

BaseService has:

```
public User getCurrentUser() {
    if(currentUser==null){
     try {
         currentUser=((MyUser) identity.getUser()).getUser();
     } catch(Exception e){
         log.warn("getCurrentUser cannot retrieve current user from session identity and currentUser has not been set programmatically");
     }
    }
    return currentUser;
}
```

And then my dynamically generated query is like this:

```
select distinct a from BusinessAccount a where a.accountType.accountTypeEnum=:a_accountType_accountTypeEnum and (a.accountType in (:a_accountType0)) 

Param name:a_accountType_accountTypeEnum value:serviceProvider 

Param name:a_accountType0 value:[org.model.accounts.AccountType@1, org.model.accounts.AccountType@2]
```

and I found out that this line is throwing the error:

```
and (a.accountType in (:a_accountType0))
```

Why is that? When I'm only executing a getResultList()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the problem, the AccountType is extending a BaseEntity that has a Version field. When I removed the extend and add Version property in AccountType, I got the same error.

The Version field:

```
@Version
@Column(name = "VERSION")
private Integer version;
```

This version field must have an initial value which is 0.